# Drupal 8 route not found

Tags: 8, routes

I keep having a 404 error no matter what I change on my routing file.

I've created a module in `modules\custom` which have :

- An info file in `modules\custom\first_module\first_module.info.yml`:

> ```
> name: First module
> core: 8.x
> type: module
> package: Training modules
> description: First Module created to learn coding in D8
> ```

- A Routing file in  `modules\custom\first_module\first_module.routing.yml`:

> ```
> first_module_hello_world:
>   path: '/hello-world'
>   defaults: 
>     _controller: '\Drupal\first_module\src\Controller\TrainingModule:helloWorld'
>   requirements:
>     _permission: 'access content'
> ```

- A controller in `modules\custom\first_module\first_module.routing.yml`:

> ```
> <?php
> /**
>  * @file
>  * Contains \Drupal\hello_world\Controller\HelloWorldController.
>  */
>
> namespace Drupal\first_module\src\Controller;
> use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
>
> /**
>  * Controller routines for hello_world module routes.
>  */
> class TrainingModuleController extends ControllerBase {
>
>  /**
>   * Return the 'Hello World' page.
>   *
>   * @return string
>   *   A render array containing our 'Hello World' page content.
>   */
>  public function helloWorld() {
>   $output = array();
>
>   $output['hello_world'] = array(
>     '#markup' => $this->t('Hello World!'),
>   );
>   return $output;
>  }
> }
> ```

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Edit: The Module is activated and I cleared the cache several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `first_module.routing.yml`, controller there is no src and you use 2:  ::

```
first_module_hello_world:
    path: '/hello-world'
    defaults: 
        _controller: '\Drupal\first_module\Controller\TrainingModule::helloWorld'
        _title: 'hello world'
    requirements:
        _permission: 'access content'
```

Also without src in drupal 8 there si no need to use  `return $output;`
Alsi class is not good. Class is TrainingModule not TrainingModuleControlle and file need to cole the some TrainingModule

```
namespace Drupal\first_module\Controller;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

/**
 * Controller routines for hello_world module routes.
 */
class TrainingModule extends ControllerBase {

 /**
  * Return the 'Hello World' page.
  *
  * @return string
  *   A render array containing our 'Hello World' page content.
  */
 public function helloWorld() {

  return array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
        '#markup' => $this->t('Hello World!'),
  );
 }
}
```

change `first_module_hello_world`: to `first_module_hello_world.help`:

make the file `first_module_hello_world.module` and write this code

```
function first_module_hello_world_help($route_name, $route_match) {
 switch ($route_name) {
  case 'first_module_hello_world.help':
    $output = '';
    return $output;
 }
}
```

Comment: Still Page not found. I guess the first thing to check is the routing file. There must be a problem there but I can't figure out which one ! otherwhise there would have been another kind of error report.

Comment: A controller in  need to be in modules\custom\first_module\src\Controller\TrainingModule.php did you chance also this class TrainingModule extends ControllerBase

Comment: Yes I copied your code in each file.

Comment: Worked with the class after rebuilding the cache ! thanks @s-a-k-a !

Comment: I'm glad that I helped..

Comment: Si helpful but with lots of mispellings :)